# Combining thumbnail rollover with image swap and Fancybox 2

Tags: image, fancybox, swap, rollover

I'm trying to combine a thumbnail rollover (which displays a larger image above the thumbs) with Fancybox.  If you take a look at this test page you'll see what I'm talking about: http://www.neptune-design.com/sites/test/products.php

When you rollover the thumbs, the large image above changes correctly. I want to have it so that when you click on the large image above, it opens an even larger image using fancybox. As you can see from my test page, the rollover works well, but when you click on the large image, it always opens up image 1, not the current image (that's been rolled over).

For now the image names are stored in a string, but they will eventually get pulled out of a database field.  Here is my code:

Some javascript for the rollover part:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function swap(image) {
         document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
     }
 </script>
```

And the rest here:

```
  <?php

  $allpics = "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg";
  $pictures = array();
  $pictures = explode(",", $allpics);

  <a href = "images/products/big/<?php echo $pictures[0]; ?>" class = "fancybox"><img id="main" src="images/products/small/<?php echo $pictures[0]; ?>" class = "bigImage"></a>
  <?php 
    for ($i=0;$i<count($pictures);$i++) { ?>
   <div class = "imageHolder" id = "thumb<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <a href="images/products/small/<?php echo $pictures[$i]; ?>" onmouseover="swap(this);" onclick="return false;"><img src="images/products/small/<?php echo $pictures[$i]; ?>" class = "smallImage"></a></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

The for loop of course gets the image file name and displays it in the thumbnail box.  How can I change this part:

```
      <a href = "images/products/big/<?php echo $pictures[0]; ?>" class = "fancybox"><img id="main" src="images/products/small/<?php echo $pictures[0]; ?>" class = "bigImage"></a>
```

so that it will open the current image in Fancybox, not always image #1.  I realize $pictures[0] refers to the image #1, I'm just not sure how to change it appropriately.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's another page illustrating what I'm trying to do: http://bloc-nc.com/projects/gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

Here I go answering my own questions again!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function swap(image) {
    document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
    var imgurl = image.href;
    var filename = imgurl.substring(imgurl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.getElementById("main2").href = "images/products/big/" + filename;
   }
 </script>
```